# Using JAXB (in JAX-RS) with JPA entity that contains ManyToMany, OneToMany relationships

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jaxb, jax-rs

I have encountered a problem when trying to write JAX-RS resource. When I have added @XmlRootElement to JPA entity that needs to be serialised to XML/JSON using JAXB and RestEasy.

The error that has been thrown:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.salonea.entities.Provider.industries, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:155)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:160)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:88)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:6
```

And also:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.salonea.entities.Provider.industries, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: pl.salonea.jaxrs.utils.ResourceList["resources"]->java.util.ArrayList[6]->pl.salonea.entities.Provider["industries"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:190)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:671)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:549)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:851)
```

And this is code of entity attribute and its annotations:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "providers")
public Set<Industry> getIndustries() {
    return industries;
}

public void setIndustries(Set<Industry> industries) {
    this.industries = industries;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I consider how to achieve such pattern of JSON response:

```
   {
    "description": "Provider 1",
    "attr1": 0,
    "attr2": 2,
    "attrN": "auction1.jpg",
    "industries": [
      {
        "link": {
       "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/v1.0/industries/5",
        "method": "GET",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    },
    {
      "link": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/v1.0/industries/6",
        "method": "GET",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    }
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need Industries to be serialized you could annotate the getter with @XmlTransient... Otherwise you could set the fetch attribute to EAGER in the @ManyToMany annotation in case you know you wont have a lot of industries per provider. If you choose that path and if you have a pointer in Industry entity back to Provider you need to annotate it with @XmlTransient to avoid the jaxb serializer to enter in an infinite circular loop.

Comment: I consider what if I will invoke getIndustries() before returning (and serializing) with JAXB this entities? If I add @XmlTransient on the other side I prevent returning Provider (current) entities related to given Industry. I consider whether there isn't such possibility to only return for such lazy fetched relationships only IDs or hypermedia links like: http://localhost:port/app/restapi/industries/id ?

Comment: or couldn't I bypass this no Session exception by wrapping JAXRS resource method somehow in one transaction maybe using some @Stateless bean and transaction annotation on method then fetching providers and than lazy loading maybe could be in one transaction...

Comment: are there any tutorials/best practices related to entities, relationships and jaxb (jaxrs) I have seen many simple with one entity that are too simple

Comment: 1-You don't have a choice to put @XmlTransient on either side of the relationship to avoid this circular loop. Yes it is considered a very good idiom in the REST world to state entities relationship with hyperlinks. You can model it using atom links which offers a standard schema for those. 2- You also could extend your Session/EntityManager lifecycle but you might end-up in the same trap you are with fetching entities EAGERly.

Comment: "state entities relationship with hyperlinks" but how I can instead of mapping this collection of related entities just map links to them, do you have any code sample?

Comment: A good start would be with the rest easy user guide for Atom links: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/#LinkHeader

Comment: I have own Link implementation (I think this Atom links aren't portable between JAX-RS implementation ex. Jersey).
Is it possible to: 
1. map in JAXB entity with FetchType.LAZY? or I must to do a) \@XmlTransient or b) change to FetchType.LAZY? I have tried to make may ProviderResource @Stateless and try to load providers.getIndustries() in \@GET method but this doesn't work i.e. continuously thorws LazyInitializationException.
2. Somehow get only relationship IDs, not loading each entity (maybe foreign keys from column) I could add some ArrayList<Link> industriesLinks; and populate with links

Comment: I suggest to throw a new question as we move away from your original one  otherwise the strings of comments will be endless. Anyway if you think my inputs have been useful to move your reasoning forward you could show it with an up vote.